# zsh: command not found: django-admin when starting a django project

Tags: python, django, pip, ubuntu-15.10

I use Ubuntu 15.10 and zsh (don't know if it can help)
So I try to install django:

```
pip install django
Downloading/unpacking django
  Downloading Django-1.9.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.6MB): 6.6MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: django
Successfully installed django
Cleaning up...
```

Everything works fine. When I do `pip freeze` I can see django is installed.

then:
`django-admin startproject mysite`

But I got this issue:
`zsh: command not found: django-admin`

Comment: Type `rehash` first, then try again

Comment: It's a shell built-in. Look around in `man zshbuiltins`.

Comment: Where is `django-admin` located? Have you tried `which django-admin` or `type django-admin`? If that fails, have you tried `find / -name django-admin`?

Comment: I have nothing. with the find I found it here `myHome/.local/bin/django-admin`

Comment: Does `django-admin.py <command>` work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found an alternative solution.
With `find / -name django-admin` I found django-admin in `myHome/.local/bin/django-admin`.

So instead of `django-admin startproject mysite` I use the full path `myHome/.local/bin/django-admin startproject mysite`

thanks to @Evert, this is why I got the problem.
his comment:

```
This is likely because you either used the --user option to pip 
install, or you set up pip in such a way that it automatically does 
that. Hence, everything gets installed in $HOME/.local. You may want
to add $HOME/.local/bin to your $PATH for the future.
```

Comment: This is likely because you either used the `--user` option to `pip install`, or you set up `pip` in such a way that it automatically does that. Hence, everything gets installed in `$HOME/.local`. You may want to add `$HOME/.local/bin` to your `$PATH` for the future.

Comment: If someone looks for this using El Capitan (osx), i found it under `$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin/`

Comment: Im in MacOS Catalina[November 2020], and I found it in: 
>     /Users/MYUSERNAME/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py

Comment: I found it under `/Users/my_user/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py`

Answer (score 13):

I faced a similar issue on Mac OS but I moved in another way. I used Virtual Environments.

First, create the virtual environment

```
python3 -m venv django-env
```

Then, use this environment

```
source django-env/bin/activate
```

Next, install django

```
python -m pip install django
```

Finally test django is working

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

In my opinion, it is better to have environments isolated to avoid O.S. settings

Comment: This worked for me, particularly for MacOS!

Comment: it worked for macos

Answer (score 10):

When I had the problem on my mac I just uninstall django and install it again but with root permissions. Now it's working good)

```
pip3 uninstall django

sudo pip3 install django
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem after updating my Mac OS to Catalina, and shell from bash to zsh.
None of the commands would work, as if all my paths were deleted.

Looking at Brady Huang's answer, doing something similar worked for me.

I made sure django was installed correctly by reinstalling it

```
pip3 uninstall django
pip3 install django
```

I found django installed under:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/django-admin
```

by running:

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/django-admin usr/local/bin
```

I was able to run django-admin again.

Answer (score 0):

My adjango-admin is located in

```
~/Library/Python/3.7/bin/django-admin
```

But I don't have it in my linked PATH which is looks like this

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

So I create a symlink to one of the bin I have in my PATH

```
sudo ln -s ~/Library/Python/3.7/bin/django-admin /usr/local/bin
```

It solves my issue

Answer (score 0):

You may be having some dependency issues.

So to avoid it happen again you need to create a virtual environment only for the current project you are doing. Like this you can avoid having issues and isolate your application.

You can [follow this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60807898/9661008) to create a virtual environment and add django in it.

Then, as soon as you create the virtual environment and activated you can pip install django and check to see whether it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Tried many stuffs but then installing the python version 3.11 and using a virtual env solved the issue. Earlier I was using 3.8.9. Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me!

1. I just Added the following in my ~/.zshrc file( you can also add it in the  ~/.bashrc file if you are not using zsh terminal)

   ```
    export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin
   ```

This solution will work not only for you django-admin command but all other python package commands that would behave in a similar way.