# virtualenv: error: the following arguments are required: dest

Tags: python, virtualenv

[image]

I can't install and configure virtual environment on python3 on my macbook pro. I was trying to install and try django for my next project but here problems started arising.

Comment: Do you have installed `virtualenv` ?. If yes then you can create virtual environment by running this command `virtualenv your_virtualenv_name`. If there are installation errors in `virtualenv` then please post screenshots of installation error(currently it seems you have just put `virtualenv` command without any parameters).

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/ Text, please! Copy/paste from the terminal. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve "virtualenv: error: the following arguments are required: dest" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61002416/how-to-solve-virtualenv-error-the-following-arguments-are-required-dest-err)

Comment: Look like your already have a virtual environnement named `env`

Answer (score 6):

**Install virtual environment in directory**

In the main directory root add the following command to create the environment:

`$ python3 -m venv venv` this code will create a folder called venv in the root. Which basically is the virtual environment folder.

Then add the following command to activate the virtual environment:

`$ source venv/bin/activate`

```
your_project_folder/
 |
 |-- your_main_app_folder/
 |         |
 |         |--Folder_with_controllers/
 |         |            settings.py
 |         |            urls.py
 |         |            ...
 |         | 
 |         |--App_folder/
 |         |--Other_app_folder/
 |
 |--venv/
```

If the code works fine your bash should look like this:

`(venv) <the_path_for_the_folder> your_project_folder %`

After activated your environment you can now install django and other packages.

p.s.: make sure you instal and activate the virtual environment folder not in the your_main_app_folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter this code:
`virtualenv env`

Answer (score 0):

```
python -m venv .
```

This will install the virtual environment in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you directory to current project directory.
Then run `python -m venv .`

This will install virtual environment in current directory. Then cd into Scripts folder `cd Scripts` and activate venv using `. activate`

[image]