# How to solve "virtualenv: error: the following arguments are required: dest" error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

As the title says, I keep on having that error and I don't know how to solve it.

The error, as the title says is

```
virtualenv: error: the following arguments are required: dest
```

The command I entered was

```
virtualenv
```

I am running this on a MAC and on python

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you ask the question, try to also explain what are you trying to do, and not only the error you get :)

If I'm guessing correctly, you're trying to create a new virtual environment.
When executing the virtualenv command you need to specify a name (dest) for it, so that it will create the virtual environment under that folder.

Your command should look like this:

```
virtualenv venv
```

where venv is the name of the folder that will get created.

See some more information here: https://programwithus.com/learn-to-code/Pip-and-virtualenv-on-Mac/

Answer (score 0):

```
path/virtualenv pythonfinance
```

this will create a virtual environment in the folder pythonfinance.

Comment: While it requires more effort, it's _much_ more useful to copy and paste code or, in this case, console data to Stack Overflow. You should avoid linking to images of code unless there's a really good reason to (e.g., highlighting an interface element of an IDE). Can you update your answer with this information directly?

Comment: thanx... i hope it's okay now??